# How to initialize widgets in android using kotlin

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I have started to learn using kotlin language in android and getting problem while initialising my button variable ,because at the time of define my variable it ask to give some initial value when I initialize with null value and bind the variable in oncreate function its gives

> kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException

here is my code

```
class AddsFragment : Fragment() {

    var Add: Button = null!!

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val Rootview = inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.clubsfragment, null, false)
        Add = Rootview.findViewById(R.id.add) as Button
        return Rootview
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `!!` operators checks if the receiver is `null` and if it is throws `KotlinNullPointerException`. So `null!!` will always throw an exception.

You can achieve what you want in the following ways:

1. Set a type of the property to `Button?`. In this case when accessing button's methods you will have to use either `?` or `!!`.

   ```
   var add: Button? = null
   // Initialize it somewhere.

   add?.setText("Text") // Calls setText if Add != null
   add!!.setText("Text") // Throws an exception if Add == null
   ```
2. Make the button a `lateinit` property.

   ```
   lateinit var add: Button
   ```
3. Make the button a `notNull` delegate property.

   ```
   var add: Button by Delegates.notNull()
   ```

In the last two cases you cannot check if the button is `null`. If you need `null` comparison to work for the variable use the first approach.

---

There're another approaches which I'm not going to describe in details in this answer. The first on is using [Kotlin Android Extensions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html). That's a compiler plugin that generates synthetic properties for your views so you don't need to call `findViewById()` and can access views with using generated properties.

The second way is to create your own delegate that will call `findViewById()` for you. It may look something like this:

```
val add: Button by bindView(R.id.add)
```

You can find an example of such delegate in the [KotterKnife](https://github.com/JakeWharton/kotterknife/) project.

Comment: So how can I initialize my variable??

Answer (score 4):

You can use Kotlin to write helper `bind` function:

```
fun <T : View> Activity.bind(@IdRes res : Int) : Lazy<T> {
    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")    
    return lazy { findViewById(res) as T }
}
```

Then you can simply define your variable once using `val` (which equals to `final` in Java):

```
class MyActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val button: Button by bind(R.id.button)
}
```

or

```
class MyActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val button by bind<Button>(R.id.button)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can initialize views in kotlin by using any one of below methods:

**1. Nullable vars**

```
private var textView: TextView? = null
…
textView = findViewById(R.id.text_view) as TextView
```

**2. lateinit**

```
private lateinit var textView: TextView
…
textView = findViewById(R.id.text_view) as TextView
```

**3. Delegates.notNull()**

```
private var textView: TextView by Delegates.notNull()
…
textView = findViewById(R.id.text_view) as TextView
```

**4. Lazy properties**

```
private val textView: TextView by lazy { findViewById(R.id.text_view) as TextView }
```

**5. Butterknife**

```
@BindView(R2.id.text_view)
internal lateinit var textView: TextView
```

**6. Kotterknife**

```
private val textView: TextView by bindView(R.id.text_view)
```

**7. Kotlin Android Extensions**

No code sample, just get the correct imports added and start using the synthetic generated properties like below.

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.<layout>.*
```

**8. Android data binding**

```
binding = FragmentLayoutBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
...
binding.textView.text = "Hello"
```

You can checkout pro/cons of each method at [Pros/cons of Android view access strategies](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/pros-cons-of-android-view-access-strategies/3160)